# Groupby separate sum with commas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python data frame and when i use this command `df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].sum()` i get the objects of column C as one because they are strings. What i want to get is all the values of C that are suitable separated with comma.

example result of what i get now:

```
    A B 
    x y klmn
    z y jk
    l c io
```

What i want:

```
A B 
x y k,l,m,n
z y j,k
l c i,o
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use join to explicitly add a separator, which you can't do with sum:

```
df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].apply(", ".join)
```

---

```
In [11]: ", ".join(["a", "b", "c"])
Out[11]: 'a, b, c'
```