# Removing duplicates from first column and retrieving comma separated values from second column using Python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have the input file which is something like:

[image: Input file:]

I want to remove the duplicates from request_id field but need the corresponding e_id for it as comma separated values.

*For Ex:*

My Output should look like:

[image: Required Output]

I tried to bring this output using dataframe
 `pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates(subset=['Request_id'], keep='last')`
But it didn't work as expected. Any suggestions to bring the desired output would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699137/groupby-separate-sum-with-commas basically do `df.groupby('Request_id')['E_id'].apply(','.join)`

Comment: @EdChum  I tried with groupby but am getting error stating `unbound method groupby() must be called with DataFrame instance as first argument (got Series instance instead)`   . Also tried converting Series.to_frame  but no luck.

Comment: Your question is unclear, is 'Request_id' the index or is the entire thing a df? The normal form is to post raw data, code to recreate your df, your attempts and the desired output

Comment: Actually it's my mistake  I have kept 'Request_id' in a list and tried using dataframe so it expected Series instance. After I changed it to DataFrame , it worked. Thanks @EdChum